# Jquery Cycle is duplicating navigation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Hello I am using the jQuery cycle plugin in a slideshow, but i am having a little problem because its duplicating the number of navigation in my code.

**Slide :**

```
$('#slide-imgs').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollLeft',
    pager : "#nav-slide",
    cleartype: true,
    cleartypeNoBg: true,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
        return '<a class="bullet-slide" href="#" rel="'+ idx +'" > </a>';
    }
});

<div id="nav-slide" class="navigation-slide" > </div>

<div id="slide-imgs" >
    <img src="<?php echo base_url( 'jobs/nome-job-0.jpg' ) ?>" alt="nome-job" />
    <img src="<?php echo base_url( 'jobs/nome-job-0.jpg' ) ?>" alt="nome-job" />
</div>
```

I have two images in my slideshow but its returning 4 link in my nav... what this could be?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Do you have more than one slideshow on the same page?

Comment: Adam : Im tryng to put this online right now...

boz : No i have just one slide in my page